# Why does routing to a route with a flat list get slower over time?

Tags: react-native, material-design, react-native-router-flux

I am building a react-native app with react-native-router-flux, and react-material-ui ... In a route I want to render a FlatList with react-material-ui cards and an image on the card. The number of cards to render is about 20 items. When I route between components that do not have flat lists the app seems to perform perfectly, and even it performs well when I route to the flatlist the first handful of times. But after a while rendering the flatlist begins to get slower and slower until the app crashes. I have used xcode instruments to look for memory leaks but do not notice any because there are only green checkmarks and no red ones, but it is noticeable that the memory in the app is increasing. Is it because of the images? Or what would cause a Flatlist to behave like this, and how can one solve this issue? Thanks, I am new with react-native development so any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Ive done some more research on the react-native-router-flux API and there are a bunch of methods there for navigating and I am wondering if maybe I am using the wrong one or somthing and I keep creating scenes instead of reusing already created scenes possibly. [docse](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md) I have been using `Actions.jump('scenekey')` 
to navigate between scenes. Is there another method here which would be better to use for navigation that would not eat up memory? Im pretty stumped because my app is pretty simple, and dont get why this is happening.

Comment: It should not get gradually slower, so best add your Component code. The fact that memory is increasing is an indication something could likely be improved.

Comment: Its possible that react-native-router-flux is the problem because if I render a flatlist with 10 Text elements with the word 'hi' in them, the memory still skyrockets. I have upated the question with a bit of code.